# How to detach on many element with Laravel Eloquant

Tags: php, laravel

I have a relationship many to many with the table Screen and Media with a pivot table Media_Screen.
I want to remove the data with the screens' id in $id_screens from the pivot table.

I did like this :

```
$id_screens = [4,5];
$screens = App\Screen::whereIn('id', $id_screens)->get();

    foreach($screens as $screen)
    {
        $screen->medias()->detach();
    }
```

It works but I'm wondering if there is not a better way to do? I tried something like this but it didn't work :

```
$id_screens = [4,5];
$screens = App\Screen::whereIn('id', $id_screens)->get();
$screens->medias()->detach();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mass detach the relationship by querying on pivot table. It'll reduces number of queries you do in the loop. In your case, you can use below code for example.

```
$screens_id = App\Screen::whereIn('id', $id_screens)
    ->select('id')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('id');

\DB::table('Media_Screen')->whereIn('id_screen', $screens_id)->delete();
```

Comment: thanks, It's what I wanted to reduce the number of queries

Answer (score 0):

You may try "high order messages" as documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages):

```
$id_screens = [4,5];
$screens = App\Screen::find($id_screens);
$screens->each->medias()->detach();
```

Comment: But using `each()` on collection makes no difference in number of database queries.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI no it doesn't, it's just cleaner.